# Removing a portion of an email address in Linux using Filters

Tags: linux, sorting, filter, formatting, paste

I have an assignment that I am working on but I cannot figure out what to do next. We were given a list of emails and we are to reformat it. 
It is given in

```
Username@imapNumber.asu.edu LastName, Firstname
```

It needs to be in the following format:

```
LastName, FirstName Username@EmailAddress
```

I am able to rearrange everything so it is in the correct format, but I cannot remove the imapNumber portion of the email. Could someone help me with this?

So far I have done the following:

To get only the email addresses I did the following command:

```
cut -d" " -f1 addressbook|cat>emails
```

To get the lastname firstname I did the following command:

```
cut -d, -d" " -f2 addressbook|cat>names
```

The information below is from a file called addressbook

```
yihuey@imap1.asu.edui Li,Yi-Huey
esolis@imap1.asu.edu Solis,Erica
eikochan@imap2.asu.edu Ismail,Eiko
calif213@imap3.asu.edu Rangel,Juvenal
tvole@imap1.asu.edu Vo-le,Trang
mwang3@imap3.asu.edu Wang,Meiping
jxiao@imap1.asu.edu Xiao,JunHui
lchen1@imap1.asu.edu Chen,Lihua
yluo4@imap1.asu.edu Luo,Yan
evraghv@imap2.asu.edu Raghuram,Edupuganti
wnatkin@imap2.asu.edu Natkin,William
carmstr@imap2.asu.edu Armstrong,Craig
rvanam@imap1.asu.edu Ram,PrasadVanam
skambam@imap1.asu.edu Kambam,SuneethaR
chr21@imap2.asu.edu Crawford,Chris
lisa60@imap3.asu.edu Robinson,Lisa
sadi1@imap1.asu.edu Adi,SrikanthReddy
dwfletc@imap1.asu.edu Fletcher,Derrick
bhancha@imap1.asu.edu Hanchate,Bhavaniprasad
rkambha@imap1.asu.edu Kambhampati,RamaKrishna
rkanumu@imap1.asu.edu Kanumuri,RangaRaju
pkotham@imap1.asu.edu Kothamachu,Pradeep
vkuruma@imap1.asu.edu Kurumaddali,Venkata
xmliu@imap3.asu.edui Liu,Xiaomei
rmahaka@imap1.asu.edu Mahakali,Radha
mmuruge@imap4.asu.edu Murugesan,Monikadevi
vpallet@imap1.asu.edu Palleti,Venkata
vshanmu@imap1.asu.edu Shanmugam,Viji
helenwei@imap2.asu.edu Wei,Helen
lxiao@imap4.asu.edu Xiao,Li
madhu@imap2.asu.edu HanumanthaReddy,Madhu
bchakka@imap2.asu.edu Chakkarabavi,Beena
ykang@imap1.asu.edu Kang,Yi
```

Comment: Do it with `awk`, then you don't have to save each column to a file.

Comment: You can use its `sub()` function to remove `imap#` from the email column.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am only able to use filters. We haven't used awk in my class yet.

Comment: Can you use `while read email name; do ... done < filename`?

Comment: Use `sed` to remove the imap number from the `emails` file.

Comment: Looking in my book, the only things it gives me to use are tr, uniq, sort, paste, and cut. I was thinking that I could use the following command: cut -d -f1 addressbook|cat>imap. This gives us the username along with the impap#.

Comment: This will be really complicated with only those 5 commands.

Comment: I realize that, I've only been using linux for about 6 weeks. Our class hasn't touched awk, sed, or perl.

Comment: I can't see how they expect you to do this with only 6 weeks of experience and those limited tools. That's more like a programming contest, not a beginning assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sed` to remove the `imap#.` from the emails.

```
cut -d" " -f1 addressbook | sed 's/@imap[0-9]*\./@/' > emails
```

ALso, there's no need to pipe to `cat`, just redirect the output of `cut` or `sed` to the file.

```
cut -d" " -f2 addressbook > names
```

And there's no point in using `-d,` in the second `cut`. Only the last `-d` option is used.